# Camel kafka logging incorrect details in messageHistory

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel, apache-kafka

I am using camel kafka component 2.19 (Latest). I am initializing kafka producer endpoint with "my-topic". but topic is calculated at the runtime say "my-error-topic" and I set it in the header so the message is produced to "my-error-topic". Everything works fine.

The problem is when messageHistory is logged, it logs initial route with the topic which I used for initialization which makes it misleading information for support guys because it gives them an idea that message is produced to "my-topic." As a workaround, I have stopped logging message history. But still I got it in logs from defaultErrorHandler.log(). Hence it is still misleading.

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is correct as it does it, as it logs the endpoint url from the route (eg you can find exactly where in the route it was). Any kind of header override is a special use-case here, you can log the headers if you use error handling in Camel where you can log anything you want, such as the exception message, stacktrace, message body, headers etc.

Comment: I logged a ticket to see if we can improve this in a future version: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11521